# Classicalities of Homotopy Type Theory

Tags: logic, homotopy-theory, constructive-mathematics, homotopy-type-theory

What are statements of HoTT that are not provable therein and thus may or may not be true in specific models, specifically models in $(\infty,1)$- topoi? I've also seen the term "classicalities" being used for such statements.

The examples I've found are:

LEM, AC, [Whitehead Principle](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Whitehead+theorem#in_homotopy_type_theory), [n-types covering](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/n-types+cover#InModels).

I had also noted the statement that " A set-indexed wedge of circles is always a 1-type" but I seem to have lost that reference.

> Are there any other such statements?

Comment: I assume you are referring to propositions that are “classically true”, that is, true in some canonical model (or Platonically true in some sense). There are all kinds of constructive theories which are (or at least seem to be likely to be) consistent with HoTT but contrary to classical logic. There are also plenty of set-theoretic propositions like the Continuum Hypothesis which should be just as independent of HoTT as they are of normal set theory.

Comment: Also, it appears that whenever $I$ is a set with decidable equality and for all $i$, $T_i$ is a connected $1$-type, the wedge of the $T_i$s is also a 1-type. This can be shown by giving the free product of the loop spaces of the $T_i$ the usual classical definition, and by using a code/decode argument. It’s not clear how to approach the more general case where $I$ may not have decidable equality.

Comment: Right of course, so in some sense anything one can prove in HoTT + LEM e.g. is as much of a classicallity as LEM itself. I was hoping for statements that are also "independent" form one another. Much like AC and CH. By the way I wasn't even aware that HoTT is so expressive when it comes to cardinals but I have found some references regarding that.